# GCP Request is prohibited by organization's policy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-shell, google-vpc

I'm trying to extract some information from GCP. I use this command `gcloud asset search-all-resources --scope=projects/projID`

But it gives me `VPC_SERVICE_CONTROLS` error:

```
User does not have permission to access projects instance (or it may not exist): Request is prohibited by organization's policy.
```

I tried troubleshooting and checked all permissions but everything's fine. Strange fact is that it works with other projects and other environments. Do I need some special configurations?

Comment: Check project ID, maybe you have used a project name. So make sure it is a project ID. [(......or it may not exist)]

Comment: yes i am using correct ProjectID.. the problem is that it works for my other colleauges but not for me and we all have same permissions

Comment: The evidence ("User does not have permission to access projects instance (or it may not exist") suggests strongly that (per @dany-l) you're using an incorrect Project ID and/or that the credentials you're using don't have the same permission. Copy and paste the command. If it works for them, it's you(r credentials).

Answer (score 1):

To search all cloud resources within the specified scope, the caller must be granted `cloudasset.assets.searchAllResources` permission on the desired scope *(can be a project, a folder or an organization)*. If not specified, the [configured project property](https://cloud.google.com//sdk/docs/configurations#setting_configuration_properties) will be used.

By running, `gcloud config get project` you'll find the configured project and to change the project, run: `gcloud config set project [PROJECT_ID]`

You may find the official documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/asset/search-all-resources).